# Dual sorting of arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sorting

I want to sort an array of names first by frequency, then alphabetically, so the result will be:

Jack (4), Dan (3), Dave (3), Alex (2), Allen (2)

(The frequency number in parenthesis is just for reference, I don't need it to display.)

Currently what I'm doing is:

```
names = ["Jack", "Dan", "Jack", "Dan", "Jack", "Dan", "Jack", "Dave", "Alex", "Allen", "Dave", "Alex", "Dave", "Allen"]
subjects = names.uniq

freq = names.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h, v| h[v] += 1; h }
subjects.sort_by {|v| [freq[v], v]}
```

The problem is that sorting just by frequency returns an array in ascending order (least frequent to most frequent) (i.e. Allen, Alex, Dan, Dave, Jack), while sorting just alphabetically goes from A to Z left-to-right (i.e. Alex, Allen, Dan, Dave, Jack).

As a result, the two field sort is doing the opposite of what I want - it's sorting by frequency and then, essentially, by *reverse*-alphabetical order (so: Alex, Allen, Dan, Dave, Jack).

I have a clumsy way of reversing it by calculating "reverse frequency" (i.e. the most frequent name gets the *lowest* number instead of the highest), which does get me to the right result, but I feel like there has to be a better way of doing it than this:

```
freq = names.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h, v| h[v] -= 1; h } # -= instead of +=
subjects.sort_by {|v| [freq[v], v]}
```

Comment: did you try `[v, freq[v]]` ?

Comment: That returns:  ["Alex", "Allen", "Dan", "Dave", "Jack"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

{ |v| [-freq[v], v] } is your best bet, I think.

I've tried a few different .reverse strategies, but they always then reverse the alphabetical ordering which you could reverse but having { |v| [freq[v], v.reverse] }.reverse just seems wrong.

Comment: Yes - this is what I was looking for - I didn't realize you could reverse the frequency ordering by just including a "-" but I figured there must be something like that. Thanks.

Comment: It is the same thing you did with your "h[v] -= 1", just in a different place. Your instincts were strong.

Answer (score 2):

```
names.group_by { |a| a }.sort_by { |a,b| [-b.size,a] }.map(&:first)
```

Output:

```
["Jack", "Dan", "Dave", "Alex", "Allen"]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
  freq = names.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h, v| h[v] += 1; h }
  freq.sort do |a, b|
    case
    when a.last > b.last
      -1
    when b.last > a.last
      1
    else
      a.first <=> b.first
    end
  end.map(&:first)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the array `names` were of modest size, I would do it like this:

```
names.uniq.sort_by { |str| [-names.count(str), str] }
  #=> ["Jack", "Dan", "Dave", "Alex", "Allen"]
```

The reason this works is that [Enumerable#sort_by](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) uses [Array#<=>](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) for pairwise comparisons of `[-names.count(str), str]`.  Please see documentation for the latter to see how that is done.

If `names` were large, it would be more efficient to first determine the frequency of each distinct element of `names`.  There are many ways to do that.  You mentioned one, @matt another.  Here's one more:

```
freq = names.each_with_object({}) { |str,h| h.update({str=>1}) { |_,o,_|o+1 } }
  #=> {"Jack"=>4, "Dan"=>3, "Dave"=>3, "Alex"=>2, "Allen"=>2}

freq.keys.sort_by { |str| [-freq[str], str] }   
  #=> ["Jack", "Dan", "Dave", "Alex", "Allen"]
```

The calculation of `freq` makes use of the form of [Hash#update](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `Hash#merge!`) that takes a block.